# how to insert jpeg files in edittext android

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way to add jpeg files to edittext in android. Basically i am creating a rich text editor in android which should have a provision to display images. Or do i need to make changes in edittext canvas for that. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

-Regards,
Ron..

Comment: i think u should post in http://android.stackexchange.com/ to get better response

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will post this question there also.

Comment: @Babu I disagree, this is a coding question. It belongs to so IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the android-richtexteditor component.

http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/

The code has been deleted from the official project but it is still available in the history.

http://android-richtexteditor.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/

Comment: Hi,  I checked this link but i am not able to find any source code or any demo. I think the project got deleted from code.google.com.

Comment: I did not recognize, that the code has been deleted. I will try to find a backup mirror.

Comment: I found the code in the svn history of the project. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks :) i am able to see through r3 revision. And it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Sorry I did not take enough time to read. You wanted an *Editable* with picture, not a simple TextView.

Anyway, the solution is maybe to catch user keys and update a webview on the fly using

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:onKeyDown("+keyCode+")");
```

You will need tight javascript/java linking. It can be somewhat tough to code but you will not be limited in terms of rich content.

**Former answer:**

You may want to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead of a TextView.

They can be very lightweight if you feed them with simple HTML.

For example, if you want to use the image `myImage.png` that you stored in your project `assets` folder, simply use:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
String richContent = "<html><body>This is text and an <b>Image</b>: <img src=\"file:///android_asset/myImage.png\" /></body></html>";
myWebview.loadData(richContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
```