# Android: Insert Bitmap in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, imagespan

I would like to insert jpeg images in edittext attached as shown below.

Stackoverflow has recommended this post but the reference projects provided are no longer valid.
[how to insert jpeg files in edittext android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579797/how-to-insert-jpeg-files-in-edittext-android)

Will there be any reference projects?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check), null);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageSpan` like this...

```
buildImageSpan(EditText et){
  SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("anystring");
  Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
  ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, "anystring", ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
  ss.setSpan(span, 0, anystring.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  et.setText(et.getText()+ss);
}
```

Comment: Does it also work if i want to attach image bitmap from gallery instead of using drawable in the apps? So the same approach will be ok?

Comment: refer this answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834643/3442067 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653027/3442067. you can convert image from storage to Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set compound drawable top bottom left right using

```
edittext.setCompoundDrawables(left,top,right, bottom);
```